# Integer linear programming formulation of boolean selection

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

Given a boolean variable $x$ and nonnegative integer variable $s$, I want to select $y = \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if} \ x = 0 \\
    s & \text{if} \ x = 1
\end{cases}$.
Currently in the problem, $s$ is the sum of $n$ boolean variables $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n$ so I want to compute $x \land x_1 + x \land x_2 + \cdots + x \land x_n$. However, computing each individual $x \land x_i$ requires its own variable and constraints and I'm wondering if its possible to use a constant number of variables and constraints.

Comment: If $s$ is an integer variable then it can't be the sum of boolean variables. If the sum is known you can just compute $xs$.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist It's possible that "s is an integer variable and s is the sum of n boolean variables x1 + ... + xn" was an informal way to say "s is an integer variable, and there is a linear equality constraint s = x1 + ... + xn".

Answer (score 3):

Use the three inequalities

$$0 \le y \le s$$

$$y \le Mx$$

$$y \ge s - M(1-x)$$

where $M$ is a large constant, chosen to be larger than the largest possible value of $s$ (e.g., $M=n+1$ in your example).